# Cant get rid of this type Error

Tags: javascript, typeerror

**Heys Guys....
Im having trouble getting rid of a type error on the 4th line of this code.
Any suggestions...???**

```
function update() {

    var numRegExp = /^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/;

    if (numRegExp.test(this.value) !== false){

    (this.value).toFixed(2);

    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

    document.forms[0].elements["sub" + i].value = calcRow(i).toFixed(2);

    document.forms[0].total.value = calcTotal().toFixed(2);

    }

    }
   else {

    alert("Invalid currency value");

    (this.value = "0.00");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toFixed()` to a number method, `this.value` is a string so convert `this.value` to a number. You can use `parseInt()/parseFloat/unary operator` to do that based on your need

```
(+this.value).toFixed(2);
```